# Continuation Line error in R

Tags: r

This feels like a very simple question, but I can't find an answer anywhere I've searched. I'm new to R and when I try to break up my code across several lines with ctrl+shift+enter, but I don't get the '+' that should start the line in the console, and I get an error message when I try to run it. Sample code is:

```
for (j in 1:length(codes)) {
currCountry <- subset(currRegion, Country.Code == codes[j])
currCountry <- currCountry[order(currCountry$variable, decreasing=FALSE),]
lines(1960:2009, currCountry$value, col="#00200070", lwd=0.8)
}
```

I get the following error: 
Error: unexpected input in "for (j in 1:length(codes)) {‚"

If I copy the same code from the online tutorial I'm doing, it works fine, but each line starts with a '+'. What can I do to get this?

Comment: What GUI are you using (standard R or RStudio)? And you're at the console or a script editing window? Are you tying this one at a time or copy/pasting? It should be the case that just pressing enter the first line should send you to a new line with a "+" since you have an open brace at that point.

Comment: I'm using Standard R. I'm in the console, should I be in a script editing window? I'm trying to type it all in and break it up over the lines, but every time I hit enter it runs whatever I've typed.

Comment: What OS and GUI version? (check `sessionInfo()`) I cannot replicate your error. For example `for(i in 1:10) {<enter>print(i)<enter>}<enter>` works for me. I get a "+" after the first enter since the previous line had an open brace. Your error message seems to have a comma (",") in it, are you sure you didn't type that?

Comment: I'm on:
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite)
definitely haven't typed any commas. are you also using ctrl+shirt+enter to go to start a new line of the code between the {}?